# Python - Tuple to grouped Dict

Tags: python, json, tuples

So I have this tuple thats returned from my database, which shows how many times the user was logged in total everyday.

```
mytuple = 
(
    ('jim', datetime.date(2017, 2, 10), 1L), 
    ('jeff', datetime.date(2017, 2, 11), 1L), 
    ('jeff', datetime.date(2017, 2, 12), 1L), 
    ('jeff', datetime.date(2017, 2, 13), 1L), 
    ('jeff', datetime.date(2017, 2, 14), 26L)
)
```

How can I format it to a Dict / Json in this way?

```
mydict = {
    {
        name: 'jeff',
        data: [
            [(2017, 2, 11), 1],
            [(2017, 2, 12), 1],
            [(2017, 2, 13), 1],
            [(2017, 2, 14), 26]
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'jim',
        data: [
            [(2017, 2, 10), 1]
        ]
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `itertools` library, it has `groupby` function to do that. Hopefully this will be faster once you have larger dataset. However, the output will be list instead of dictionary, not quite the same as you asked.

```
import datetime
from itertools import groupby

mytuple = [('jim', datetime.date(2017, 2, 10), 1), 
    ('jeff', datetime.date(2017, 2, 11), 1), 
    ('jeff', datetime.date(2017, 2, 12), 1), 
    ('jeff', datetime.date(2017, 2, 13), 1), 
    ('jeff', datetime.date(2017, 2, 14), 26)]

group_dict = []
for key, group in groupby(mytuple, lambda x: x[0]):
    group_dict.append({'name': key, 'data': [[g[1], g[2]] for g in group]})
```

Here you do `groupby` and provide function for it using the first key of the tuple e.g. here `lambda x: x[0]`. Data in this case is element of each group index 1 and 2.

You can also use the transform datetime in tuple format too, something like following:

```
group_dict = []
for key, group in groupby(mytuple, lambda x: x[0]):
    data = [[(g[1].year, g[1].month, g[1].day), g[2]] for g in group]
    group_dict.append({'name': key, 'data': data})
```

Comment: Hadn't thought of using `itertools` - nice!

Comment: thanks @asongtoruin! just an alternative to your answer :)

Comment: Great job @asongtoruin @titipat! I did a test on both of your code to see how fast they were, they both perform equally as quick on a single run and were hard to get accurate readings, however running them both over 10,000 times, @titipats got an average of 0.181068181992 seconds, and @asongtoruin was over 10 seconds, most likely due to `with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:` :) Thank you both for your help! Fantastic work

Comment: @Slopax the `open('output.txt', 'w') as f:` was in case you actually wanted to export the values to a JSON file, it's not necessary for the generation of the object.

Comment: @asongtoruin ah yes, with that removed and `json.dump` changed to `.dumps`, it took 0.779141187668 seconds :) Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Slopax sounds great and glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime
import json

mytype = (
    ('jim', datetime.date(2017, 2, 10), 1L), 
    ('jeff', datetime.date(2017, 2, 11), 1L), 
    ('jeff', datetime.date(2017, 2, 12), 1L), 
    ('jeff', datetime.date(2017, 2, 13), 1L), 
    ('jeff', datetime.date(2017, 2, 14), 26L)
)

mydict = {}

for name, date, count in mytype:
    if name not in mydict:
        mydict[name] = []
    mydict[name].append(((date.year, date.month, date.day), count))

print mydict
print json.dumps(mydict)
```

Comment: this doesn't get the desired format - note `name: 'jeff'`

Comment: @asongtoruin I get that it is not exactly the desired format, but what about 'jeff' that you're saying?

Comment: The question asks for a dictionary with `name` as a key, you have provided one with the user's name as the key (rather than the value)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following:

```
import datetime
import json

mytype = (
    ('jim', datetime.date(2017, 2, 10), 1L),
    ('jeff', datetime.date(2017, 2, 11), 1L),
    ('jeff', datetime.date(2017, 2, 12), 1L),
    ('jeff', datetime.date(2017, 2, 13), 1L),
    ('jeff', datetime.date(2017, 2, 14), 26L)
)

output = []

def date_to_ymd_tuple(input_date):
    return (input_date.year, input_date.month, input_date.day)

for user in set(item[0] for item in mytype):
    output.append({'name': user,
                   'data': [[date_to_ymd_tuple(x[1]), x[2]] for x in mytype if x[0] == user]
                   })

print output

with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(output, f)
```

which will write out

```
[{"data": [[[2017, 2, 10], 1]], "name": "jim"}, {"data": [[[2017, 2, 11], 1], [[2017, 2, 12], 1], [[2017, 2, 13], 1], [[2017, 2, 14], 26]], "name": "jeff"}]
```